# Subtract one from last nonzero value in row; multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have created a dataframe with dates and the amount of days each month from a dataframe of arrival and departure dates. This dataframe can be n columns long.

```
    2021-01 2021-02 2021-03
0   0       0       4
1   0       2       1
2   0       5       0
3   0       4       4
4   10      2       0
```

What I want to do is: Select the last column with a value that is nonzero and subtract 1.

Basically looking like this afterwards:

```
    2021-01 2021-02 2021-03
0   0       0       3
1   0       2       0
2   0       4       0
3   0       4       3
4   10      1       0
```

I have tried using numpy with:

```
df2 = df2[np.arange(df2.shape[0]),(df2!=0).cumsum(1).argmax(1)] - 1
```

But this does not seem to work correctly with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Get rows with zero then filter and keep only the one with lowest index

```
has_zero = df.eq(0, axis=0)
all_zero_rows = has_zero.dot(df.columns.str.split())
col_to_replace = all_zero_rows.explode().drop_duplicates(keep="last").sort_index()[0]
df.loc[df.index[-1], col_to_replace] = df.loc[df.index[-1], col_to_replace] -1

print(df)

    2021-01 2021-02 2021-03
0   0       0       3
1   0       2       0
2   0       4       0
3   0       4       3
4   10      1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean always select the last column or the last column that has at least one nonzero value?

Edit: Alright, here goes a possible solution. I did this on a numpy array because doing computation on dataframes can be problematic.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

list = [[0,0,4],[0,2,1],[0,5,0],[0,4,4],[10, 2, 0]]
nplist = np.array(list)

lastcol = np.where(nplist[:,-1]==0, nplist[:,-1], nplist[:,-1] - 1)
nplist[:,-1] = lastcol

df = pd.Dataframe(nplist, index=['2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03'])


nplist
array([[ 0,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  2,  0],
       [ 0,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  4,  3],
       [10,  2,  0]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping!
We can assume that every column has at least one nonzero value. I want to select the last nonzero value for every row and then subtract -1.

Comment: This one works only for the first 2 rows. The other ones are ignored. For example the last row is still: 10   2    0. This one should also subtract 1 from the last value that is bigger than 0. So it becomes 10  1   0.

Comment: Another possibility I'm thinking of is adding a new column at the end with all 0. Then I could try to check if the next column contains a zero. If yes, then -1.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to do. Should I delete my answer or it is helpful?